# Emacsclient won't open file buffer directly in new frame from CLI

Tags: emacs

Sometimes it's nice to pop up Emacs (v 25.1.1) in a new frame to edit
a file I've specified in my shell.  E.g., I'm using

```
% emacsclient --create-frame .../path/to/file.txt &
```

to attempt to create a frame with `file.txt` as the buffer.

According to `emacsclient --help`, this should work.

The problem is that Emacs just opens up a new frame with some other
buffer it's already working with (or no buffer if server wasn't running), rather than `file.txt`.  Is this
just an `emacsclient` bug, or do I need to use some other invocation
to put the CLI-specified file into the new frame.

Yes, I can `C-x b file.txt` to select it since it's now an active
buffer, but that defeats the point of the CLI convenience (which is
actually a little alias, `e`).

Comment: I can't reproduce, it works for me. Which version of Emacs are you using? Have you tried this with a plain Emacs to rule out the possibility that it's related to something in your init file in some way?